# How to calculate every other weeks with DateTime?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have chat app. I want allow user message other user only every other week. For example:

- Week 1 (allowed
- Week 2 (not allowed)
- Week 3 (allowed)
- Week 4 (not allowed)
  ...

How I can do this? I want write conditional so can say:

```
if (allowedWeek) {
sendMessage
}
```

Maybe can use something like this?

```
DateTime.now().isAfter(X) && DateTime.now().isBefore(Y)
```

How I can tell DateTime this?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can get week of the year by this package, [week_of_year](https://pub.dev/packages/week_of_year), and decide which week to talk which is not:

```
import 'package:week_of_year/week_of_year.dart';

void main() {
  final date = DateTime.now();
  print(date.weekOfYear); // Get the iso week of year
  print(date.ordinalDate); // Get the ordinal date
  print(date.isLeapYear); // Is this a leap year?
}
```